# Hi, I want to write a Python code that looks if the numbers are even and if the numbers are even print it. Thanks for helping :)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numbers

I hope you understand my question. If the list called nums have even numbers ı want it to print them.

```
import random
nums = [951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
    615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
    958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470,
    743, 527]

if nums % 2 == 0:
    for i in nums:
        print(i)
if i == 3:
    b
else:
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just rearrange this code:

```
# loop trough the list
for i in nums:
    # check if number is even
    if i % 2 == 0:
        # print it
        print(i)
```

Comment: you could also do `if not i & 1:`

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the *list* is divisible by 2(which is impossible):

```py
f = [i for i in nums if i%2 == 0]
for i in f:
  print(i)
```